# If an extension of a harmonic function on the boundary of the unit disc is not continuous, can we get the function back by the poisson formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that if a harmonic function $f$ in the unit disc can be continuously extended to $\tilde{f}$ on the boundary and if $\tilde{f}$ is continuous, then we can get $f$ by $f(z)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\tilde{f}(e^{i\theta})P_r(\theta-\varphi)d\varphi$. I was wondering whether this formular can be adopted if $\tilde{f}$ is not continous on the boundary? And if we can't, does the formular still hold if $\tilde{f} $ has only finitely many discontinuities on the boundary?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "can be continuously extended"? If this does not mean that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on the closed unit disk, then how is $\widetilde f$ defined?

Comment: for example, if $\tilde{f}$ on the boundary is like $\tilde{f}(\alpha)=0 $ when $0<\alpha<\pi$ and $\tilde{f}(\alpha)=1 $ when $\pi<\alpha<2\pi$, can we still use the formula?

Comment: There is no chance if you define $\widetilde f$ on the boundary without any reference to the behaviour of $f$ inside.

Comment: why can't I just say $f$ is harmonic and without further conditions?

Comment: the problem is motivated by the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}arg(z)$ when $z\in \mathbb{H}$, then if we map the upper half plane to the unit disc, then we should have $f$ is harmonic and the function looks like $\tilde{f}$ on the boundary.

Comment: If $\tilde{f}(e^{i\theta}) = \lim\limits_{\rho \to 1} f(\rho e^{i\theta})$ exists, is "nice enough" and the convergence is also "nice enough", you have the Poisson formula. I don't remember off the top of my head what exactly "nice enough" is.

Comment: This is OK if $f$ is in some Hardy class $h^p$, $p>1$. In this case, $\widetilde f(e^{i\theta})$ exists almost everywhere as defined by Daniel and Poisson's formula holds (this is "Fatou's theorem"). For example, this holds if $f$ is bounded in the open unit disk.

Comment: Yup, also see   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space#Hardy_spaces_on_the_unit_circle